# How to play a video in a pop-up window when the user clicks on the video in an Aura Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, community, jquery

I am using iFrame to play a video, but the video runs on that page/screen itself.
But I want that when the user clicks on the video a pop-up/modal screen comes where the user can watch the video.
I have used the below code. What can be the possible changes to achieve this.

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">  
    <div class="slds-size_12-of-12">
        <div class="slds-p-around_x-small">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.lstContentDoc}" var="CD">
                <aura:if isTrue="{!CD.JP_lessonID__c==v.Param}">
                <aura:if  isTrue="{!and(CD.FileType=='PDF',CD.JP_Video_URL__c!='')}">
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-gutters slds-wrap">
                <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-medium-size_3-of-12 slds-large-size_3-of-12">
                    <span><iframe style="width:-webkit-fill-available;border:1px solid #ccc;" src="{!CD.JP_Video_URL__c}"></iframe></span>
                            <div class="slds-media__body">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <div class="slds-page-header__name">
                                        <div class="slds-page-header__name-title">
                                            <h1>
                                                <a class="slds-page-header__title slds-truncate" title="{!CD.Title}" onclick="{!c.previewFile}" data-Id="{!CD.ContentDocumentId}">{!CD.Title}</a>
                                            </h1>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>

                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                   </aura:if>
                   </aura:if>
               </aura:iteration>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for this I created a div with z-index=1 and made the iframe's z-index -1, so whenever user clicks on the video due to to z-index it gets click on the div which pops up a modal

```
                <div class="video_overlays" onclick="{! c.openModel }" style="z-index:999;position:absolute;" aura-id="custom" data-attriVal="{!CD.JP_Video_URL__c}"> </div>
                <span><iframe id="my_iframe" style="min-width:300px;height:150px;z-index:-999;" src="{!CD.JP_Video_URL__c}" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"
mozallowfullscreen="mozallowfullscreen" 
msallowfullscreen="msallowfullscreen" 
oallowfullscreen="oallowfullscreen" 
webkitallowfullscreen="webkitallowfullscreen" frameborder="0" ></iframe></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in Html using css.

You can also write custom css in your aura component rather then using iframe.

Below is the code  for your reference

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.popup .popuptext {
visibility: hidden;
background-color: #555;
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 6px;
padding: 8px 0;
z-index: 1;
bottom: 125%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -80px;
}
.popup .show {
visibility: visible;
-webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
from {opacity: 0;} 
to {opacity: 1;}
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
from {opacity: 0;}
to {opacity:1 ;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="text-align:center">
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()" ><button>Preview</button>
<video class="popuptext" id="myPopup" style="width:800px;" >
<source src="dolby-atmos-intro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
popup.classList.toggle("show");

if (popup.paused){ 
    popup.play(); 
    }
  else{ 
    popup.pause();
    }

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please tell me if you need more help.

Comment: Hi actually I want the user to click on the video and that opens a modal where the video is played not a button. Can you give any suggestion for that